# Cannot change version or build number in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, version

I'm trying to change the version and build number in iOS project in Xcode (under `Targets->General->Identity`), but for some reason no matter what I type, my typing is removed and the value won't change.  Is this not the correct place to modify this value?

Going to `Targets->General->Info` allows me to change the value, but doesn't remember the change after I navigate away from the screen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your project navigator on the left you should have a file named AppName-Info.plist. You can change the Build Version along with a bunch of other project settings here.

Comment: Well that worked.  Any idea why I have to do it there and not the obvious place?

Comment: I had the same issue. When you set "Build version" by navigating to --> Target --> General --> Identity , It has to write this information in your "App-info.plist" file. If this file is locked somehow , this kind of issue will happens.

Comment: That was a lost hour. Perforce locks all files. Xcode typically complains when this is so, but in this case silently fails and lets you edit the build number (but saves it nowhere).

Comment: I spend days ... DAYS and answer saved me to have a supposed last day as a dev :) ... Xcode 14

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the info.plist file was open on vscode. Thats why xcode was unable to modify the file. So make sure your project or its file is not open in another ide / editor. It still not works, try restarting your mac

Comment: I was previously changed when the build was running in another terminal. But tried again after everything is settled ..worked...